# Using Managed Service Accounts with Component Services

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, com+

A web-site I've been tasked to deploy uses some COM+ components that connect to SQL using a trusted connection.  The Web-site is a classic ASP site set to run under IIS7 on Server 2008.

The developer had said that the COM+ components should be set to log on as the interactive user - that is clearly wrong as such a thing won't exist under normal conditions, it worked for them as they were logged on to the test server using RDP and their ID had rights to access the database.

Ideally I would configure the COM+ components to use a Service Account.

However, our organisation has mandated the use of Server 2008 Managed Service Accounts rather than traditional Service Accounts.  I've tried to use an MSA in the COM+ identity dialog but it doesn't like the fact that the password is left blank.  I suspect that MSAs are not supported by COM+ but my web search skills can't find verification of that anywhere.

This seems another ideal place to use an MSA but I suspect we will have to fall back to a traditional service account in this case.

My question is has anyone else tried to use an MSA with COM+ and had success (entering credentials directly into the registry for instance)?  Failing that any reference citing that MSAs don't work with COM+ would be useful evidence when I justify the use of a traditional Service Account.

Many thanks

** UPDATE **
In the end we created traditional service accounts for the identity of our COM+ services as we couldn't find any help on using MSA's

Comment: I can confirm the problem with DCom. The dialog seems not be the problem, since I successfully use DCOMPerm.exe (it is writing the vaules to the registry) to set the runas user and password. The DCom-Server is not running with a GMSA user (with and without $ in the end of the username)...so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, and I don't have an answer. I do have a suggestion, but not enough points to make comments.

Try moving on from MSA to GMSA. If you set the COM+ app to run as a service, instead of running as a DCOM process, maybe you can set the service to a GMSA instead. The DCOM GUI allows you to set the component to run as a service.

1. On the Identity page, set the `Identity` to `Network Service`
2. On the Activation page,

   - Set the `Activation type` to be `Server Application`
   - Select the `[*]  Run Application as NT Service`
3. Now your Service will show up and you should be able to set the Log On to the GMSA

Your application may or may not work in this environment, so test it.